# MVN package install error javac: invalid target release: 1.8

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to install [this from git](https://github.com/thomasjungblut/glove).

(I am running Ubuntu.) I'm getting this error

```
[WARNING] The POM for de.jungblut.common:thomasjungblut-common:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ glove ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/nat/workspace/Glove/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ glove ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ glove ---
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /home/nat/workspace/Glove/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid target release: 1.8
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.782s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 27 14:33:32 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project glove: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] javac: invalid target release: 1.8
[ERROR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

I have Google'd this, and it sounds like my Java might be located in the wrong place? That or there is a problem with the POM file?

Comment: You most likely have an older version of the JDK than JDK 8 installed. Make sure you have JDK 8 installed.

Comment: make your `JAVA_HOME` point to JDK 8, `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/JDK`

Comment: Thanks, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, I needed to update JDK to JDK 8. This is what I used:

> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Once it was installed, I additionally needed to add `sudo` before `mvn clean package install`

It worked like a charm. Thanks to @Jesper